# hint didn't work in edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I use `Hint` and it works in emulator, but when I install the code in the phone, Hint doesn't work.

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="نام"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/fname" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeActionLabel="Next"> 
</EditText>
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="نام خانوادگی"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/lname" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeActionLabel="Next">
</EditText>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you have the font available on your device?

Comment: no I'm not sure! but i didn't set any font in my code!

Answer (score 3):

Copy the `String` in the strings.xml (means your relevant language) and then give the hint as

```
android:hint="@string/strname"

<resources>

  <string name="strname">نام خانوادگی</string>

</resources>
```

The above will be work if the device will support your language.

`android:singleLine="true"` remove this from your edittexts then you can see the hints

Comment: when i use English characters instead of Persian, it also doesn't work .

Comment: i think there is a problem with `android:gravity="right"`. when i change it to `left` hint is displayed in the emulator. check it once

Answer (score 1):

This issue is actually an infamous bug in android `EditText`. When using `singleLine="true"` or `maxLines="1"` or generally anything that trigger `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` the `EditText` in Layout stage fail to render **RtL** hint correctly..

If your language layout direction is RtL you can simply solve this problem by `setting gravity="right|center_vertical"` to your `EditText`.

P.S: This Issue has been on **IssueTracker** for a long time but there hasn't been any fix since. You can help this issue resolves faster by starring this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36924615

Answer (score 0):

the hint as Persian or other Unicode language 
when you define InputType for EditBox doesn't
show. you should delete the

```
android:inputType="..."
```